# Django: How can i detect object request in admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

To be more detailed, i have got list of objects in admin panel named Images

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d/', 
    verbose_name=_('Image'), default='default.png')
    album = models.ForeignKey('Album', related_name='images')
    category = TreeForeignKey(Category, null=True) 
    likes = GenericRelation('Like', related_name='image_likes', null=True)
    is_main = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_slider = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    seen = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    seen_by_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['album', 'get_owner', 'is_main', 'is_slider','total_likes', 'seen', 'image_tag', ]
    list_filter = ['album', 'album__owner', 'is_main', 'is_slider', 'album__created_at']
    search_fields = ['album__name']
    list_per_page = 15
```

Whenever *admin* or any other *superuser* enters to any `Images.object` the `seen_by_admin` field should be changed to `seen_by_admin = True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the save_model method:

```
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.seen_by_admin=True
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

More info:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model